# Can’t get my logic Formula to return a date

Tags: custom-list

I want my formula to look up the type of award in one Colum and then take the date from the Proposed Presentation date minus a set number of days and return the new date however my formula is only retuning ([Proposed Presentation Date]-120) not the actual date not sure how to fix this.

```
=IF(Award="AAM","([Proposed Presentation Date]-30)",IF(Award="ARCOM","([Proposed Presentation Date]-60)",IF(Award="MSM","([Proposed Presentation Date]-120)",IF(Award="BN COA","([Proposed Presentation Date]-30)"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula seems to be incorrect. That should be something like below

```
=IF(Award="AAM",([Proposed Presentation Date]-30),IF(Award="ARCOM",([Proposed Presentation Date]-60),IF(Award="MSM",([Proposed Presentation Date]-120),IF(Award="BN COA",([Proposed Presentation Date]-30)))))
```

Also set the data type retuned from this formula as Date and Time.

Hope this helps